# Why does Twilio Javascript Voice SDK sendDigits on repeat?

Tags: javascript, twilio

I am creating a basic web caller using Twilio Javascript SDK, with php backend. Using `call.sendDigits()` from the javascript, I can successfully send digits from an onscreen dialpad. However, when I do this, there is a repeating keypress tone until I hang up, and if I press another key, they  are both repeating in the same way. Logging from my listener shows that the method is only called once.

```
  const dialpad = document.querySelectorAll("#dialpad button");

  dialpad.forEach(dp => dp.addEventListener('click', function(e){
    e.stopPropagation();
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log("sending " + this.innerText);
    call.sendDigits(this.innerText);
  }) );
```

There is no indication in the docs that this would require a corresponding back end action, but that could potentially be the problem. Thank you

Comment: You are doing addEventListener inside of your forEach

Comment: Yes, intentionally. That adds a listener for each key in the dialpad. This is a common structure, but the log also shows only one key is pressed.

Answer (score 1):

So this is not related to Twilio it appears.

I was calling my Android cell phone, which had both speaker and mic muted to avoid feedback, and using good, ear covering headphones on the computer for similar reasons. Nonetheless, there was no problem calling to a business landline, or calling this same phone when it was physically separated from the computer. For some reason, it was overriding the mic and speaker settings when it received the tone, and created a reverberation loop.